# Trying Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 10 from USB

Tags: usb

How do I end the session trying it out with Ubuntu on USB stick? I did not select install.

Comment: Just reboot your computer.

Answer (score 2):

Click the "power" icon in the upper right corner and select "Reboot".

You will be asked to remove the Ubuntu Live media and press Enter.

After you do it, your computer will reboot as if you never tried Ubuntu.

Comment: Selecting Shutdown works too... you will be asked to remove Live media, and machine shuts off.

Answer (score 0):

### Bootable ISO File on USB

If your bootable USB uses GRUB 2 to boot an ISO file, that is stored on a NTFS partition, the only way to shut down is to press the computer power button. This will not harm a Live USB.

You can change the format of your ISO file partition to FAT32 or ext2, 3 or 4 and the computer will shut down normally.